# My Bitcoin Transaction Has Been Stuck For 9 days

Tags: transactions

What can i do to speed it up more? I have used the accelerators and re-broadcast it myself many times but it has not moved. I sent with a low fee by accident.

Txid: dc0b8a1174b1277bc10b1e80a8715b18ebcab60550dcfa694b041f3acee5c407

Answer (score 0):

You say that you have re-broadcast the transaction.  If so, I **assume** you re-broadcast with a higher fee (i.e., double spend).  If so, then the newer transaction is the one that you should be looking to confirm.  If not, then try the rebroadcast (i.e., double spend) again.  For further discussion, see [this question and its answers](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it.)

Comment: sorry i have not rebroadcast just used accelerators